# How can I separate targets for bootstrap navigation and still have fade

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation, fade

Is it possible to create a navigationbar with bootstrap where I don't navigate to tabs within the same html page but instead navigate to different html pages? And I also want to keep the fade in style.

It seems that it should be possible cause for a large page it seems impracticle to have all in the same html page.

```
<body class="page"> 
<div id="navigationbar">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills centerdiv span5">
      <li class="active"><a href="#main" data-toggle="tab">Main</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about" data-toggle="tab">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#open" data-toggle="tab">Open</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="tab">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I instead write something like

```
<body class="page"> 
<div id="navigationbar">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills centerdiv span5">
      <li class="active"><a href="main.html">Main</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="open.html">Open</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The targets is in the first style contained in  tags with class fade but this doesn't work if I separate the targets in different pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set `class="active"` to navbar links in their respective files.

If you have lot of pages, having navigation in every page can be painful because if you cange it in one place you have to change it in every other.
You can move the navigation bar into separate file and do some scripting. For example in PHP you would have something like this:

```
<li<?php active('main.html'); ?>><a href="main.html">Main</a></li>
```

and you would need some function like this:

```
function active($file) {
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/'.$file) {
        echo ' class="active';
    }
}
```

Note that this is oversimplified. You would need to strip query string and also this wouldn't work if files aren't in root of domain.

You would insert the menu to pages like this

```
<?php include __DIR__.'/navigation.php'; ?>
```

You can also use some templating system to make it more simple for you. [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) could be interesting for you.

Example menu: https://github.com/rsms/rsms.github.com/blob/master/_layouts/default.html#L78

Comment: Thanks, thats an alternative but the first response isn't correct. As to getting the navbar "highlighted" correctly I already know how to use **class="active"** I've tried to use class="active" but it doesn't support the "fade" style which happens when navigating between tabs in the same html file.